# How to get rid of static electricity on a plastic slide

Tags: antistatic, static-electricity

I've got a indoor spiral slide which appears have a large amount of static building. It frequently gives little shocks to people going down the slide. I've also got WS1825 addressable light strips on the outside of the slight which go haywire when someone goes down the slide. I believe this is because of the static charge.

As I understand it, I need to ground the slide to provide a way for the static electricity to reach earth. But since this is inside, that's easier said then done.

Is there a good way to get a ground to earth in this situation? Do I have any alternatives?

Comment: Maybe there's some kind of coating you can put on the slide to conduct the static electricity, or prevent it being created.

Comment: Just call it a feature.

Comment: Turn up the humidity. I would think a grounded wire mesh on the outside would help somewhat...reduce the distance charge has to slog through from any point on the slide before getting to a low resistance ground connection. Slides always have tons of static though. Carbon impregnated paint on the inside? Might mess up clothes though if it leaches

Answer (score 1):

> As I understand it, I need to ground the slide to provide a way for the static electricity to reach earth. But since this is inside, that's easier said then done.

Close. Your slide is plastic, i.e. made of a good isolator. Grounding one point of your slide won't help much; then, no charge can build up at that point, but that doesn't help anywhere else.

So, you need to make the sliding surface conductive. Doesn't have to be a *good* conductor – just ever so slightly conducting that the small high-voltage charges will rather "flow away" to ground than make lightning.

Luckily, there's anti-static spray, especially made for e.g. casings of sensitive electronics. However, since your problem is a large plastic slide: I think there's cheap anti-static sprays for clothing. Clothing that needs that is either silk or synthetic, i.e. isomorphic to plastic slides ;) So try these.